# Reporting in Team Foundation Service

Tags: tfs, reporting, azure-devops

Does anyone have any experience/hints/tips of querying the data contained within Team Foundation **Service** (please note not Team Foundation **Server**).

Team foundation Service is a great tool- its even better that its still currently free to use.

I'm trying to query our implementation to see what our initial time estimates were on a sprint by sprint basis.

I've looked at OData but can't find this level of detail in the calls. To be honest I've run the queries provided at https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/ but can't get any further info than seeing the project / teams created.

I've looked at the demo code that people have created using windows store apps, but as I'm running VS2012 on Windows7 I can't get the apps to work for me.

I've had a look at running queries but from what I can see it only gives you the position now and not at the start of the sprint.

Any help / tips you can provide will be gratefully accepted as I've been banging my head on this one for too long now.

It should be this difficult to find out some metric information - should it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @RinoTom - I don't want to seem petty but removing my name from the question. Is it that important or offensive? If that is all you've got to worry about or do....

Comment: **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**

_Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers._

This is a Stack Overflow [behavior model](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to use the Team Foundation Server SDK?  It works against Team Foundation Service as well.  Here's a link to the MSDN Documentation to get you started with the TFS SDK:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb130146.aspx